# Computing operator norm of a matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

In my notes I  have that $\left\|\, \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\right\| = 2+\sqrt{2}$; but I'm struggling to get this.
Here's what I have:

$$\left\|\, \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\right\| ^2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left\|\, \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right\| ^2=$$ 
$$ \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left\| \begin{bmatrix}3x_1+x_2\\ x_1+x_2\end{bmatrix}\right\|^2 = 2 \sup_{\|x\|=1} 5x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2 + x_2^2$$

Using Lagrange multipliers, if I set $F(x_1,x_2) = 5x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2 + x_2^2$ and $g(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 +x_2^2$ (where we constrain to $g=1$); then I set $\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,\lambda) = F + \lambda g$.  Setting the partial derivatives equal to zero, I compute:

$$\partial_{x_1}\mathcal{L} = 2(5x_1+2x_2+\lambda x_1) = 0$$
$$\partial_{x_2}\mathcal{L} = 4x_1+2x_2+2\lambda x_2=0$$
$$\partial_{\lambda}\mathcal{L} = x_1^2+x_2^2-1=0$$

The only conclusion I can get is that $x_i\neq 0 $ from the last equation plus the fact that we are restricting ourselves to $\|x\|=1$.

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249047/i-am-not-sure-how-to-calculate-this-norm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with Lagrange multipliers is unnecessarily painful, but here we go:

The last equation should be $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$. You have the system
\begin{align}
(5+\lambda)x_1+2x_2&=0 \\
2x_1+(1+\lambda)x_2&=0 \\
x_1^2+x_2^2&=1.
\end{align}
Since you cannot have $x_1=x_2=0$, the first two equations do not admit the zero solution. This forces the determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}5+\lambda&2\\2&1+\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0.
$$
This gives $\lambda=-3\pm2\sqrt2$, and $x_2=-(-1\pm\sqrt2)x_1$. You can confirm all the solutions with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(5%2Bz)x%2B2y%3D0,+2x%2B(1%2Bz)y%3D0,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1). Your sup will be achieved when both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive. That is
$$
10x_1^2+2x_2^2+8x_1x_2=10\,\left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2\right)^2+2\,\left(\frac12(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\right)^2+8\,\left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2\right)\left(\frac12(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\right)\\
=6+4\sqrt2=(2+\sqrt2)^2.
$$

---

Now for a non-painful way: since your matrix is selfadjoint, its operator norm is the largest eigenvalue. The characteristic polynomial is 
$$
(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-1=\lambda^2-4\lambda+2,
$$
with roots 
$$
\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-8}}2=2\pm\sqrt2.
$$
Thus,
$$
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\right\|=2+\sqrt2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first two partial derivatives gives a linear system of equations in $(x_1, x_2)$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5-\lambda & 2 \\ 2 & 1 + \lambda \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since you need a non-trivial solution, the system matrix has to be singular, i.e.,
$$ (5-\lambda) \, (1+\lambda) - 4 = 0.$$
Now, you should be able to continue.